# Como integrar Chart.js em uma aplicação Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, chart

Olá, meus caros amigos! Eu estou criando uma aplicação Electron na qual devo gerar gráficos. Tudo ofline!

Estou enfrentando o seguinte problema: Meu gráfico não aparece na minha página! Como mostrado na imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas, com uma inspeção no html inspector eu consigo ver que o `<canvas>` que deveria mostrar o gráfico foi criado, como mostardo na iamgem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A única coisa que fiz até o momento foi a instalação do chart.js com o seguinte comando `npm install chart.js --save`.

Meu código está abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Análise de óleo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="cabecalho">
        <h1 class="titulo">Nome da aplicação</h1>
    </header>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        <script>
            var chart = require("electron-chartjs");
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            // The type of chart we want to create
            type: 'line',

            // The data for our dataset
            data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
    });
            </script>
        </div>
    <script>require('./js/renderer')</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como pode ser visto, eu estou tentando reproduzir o exemplo oficial da documentação do Chart.js (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/), a única modificação foi a linha `const { chart } = require('electron-chartjs');`, que eu creio ser a forma correta de importar a biblioteca do chart.js para ser usada.

Bom, meu palpite seria que eu estou ignorando um passo importante na hora de configurar o Chart.js e o importar para dentro do arquivo e poder utilizá-lo.

Desde já, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Por que `const { chart } = require('electron-chartjs');`? Na [documentacao nao fala isso](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-chartjs), mostra simplismente `const chart = require('electron-chartjs')`.

Comment: Oi @CmteCardeal Cardeal, eu tentei dessa forma `const chart = require('electron-chartjs')` e não funcionou... Daí tentei da forma indicada na pergunta.

Por acaso, você enxerga algum outro detalhe que me passou despercebido e possa estar causando o comportamento inadequado?

Comment: Sim, apesar de nunca ter usado Electron, tem umas coisas estranhas. Tem uma `</div>` que nao estar aparecendo onde ele foi aberta, e, por que voce usou `require('electron-chartjs')` se o pacore que voce instalou foi `chart.js`? Acho que deveria ser `var Chart = require('chart.js');` para que depois voce fizesse `var chart = new Chart(ctx, {...});`. Esse pacote `electron-chartjs` nao e atualizado desde 2017, logo nao recomendo voce usar ele.

Comment: Entendi @CmteCardeal muito obrigado pela ajuda. Eu mudei para `var Chart = require('chart.js');` e não havia funcionado... Mas, troquei o id do canvas para `<canvas id="chart"></canvas>` e o chart detro do getElemen `getElementById('chart')` e está funcionando!

Eu sempre fazia várias alterações, mas no final das contas era algo simples: O id do canvas e esse detalhe que você falou (que fez toda diferença, eu creio). 

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Atualizando a pergunta: O problema foi resolvido! Graças às contribuições do @CmteCardeal.

Basicamente, estava importando o módulo errado `require('electron-chartjs')`, quando o certo é `require('chart.js')`. Além disso, estava pecando no id do canvas que deveria mostrar o gráfico. o código atualizado segue abaixo:

```
        <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
            <script>
                var Chart = require('chart.js');
                var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
                var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                // The type of chart we want to create
                type: 'line',

                // The data for our dataset
                data: {
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'My First dataset',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
        }]
    },
    // Configuration options go here
                options: {}
});
            </script>
```